# c++ inheritance with method overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Very simple example of c++ inheritance :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
 public :
 virtual void print(A a){
  cout<<"a"<<endl;
 }
};
class B : public A {
 public :
  virtual void print(A a){
  cout<<"a2"<<endl;
 }
virtual void print(B b){
  cout<<"b"<<endl;
}
};

int main(){
 B b;
 A &a = b;
 a.print(b);
 return 0;
}
```

Why does this output a2? 
I would have expected this to be effectively the same as :
     `b.print(b)`
thanks!

Comment: It's called `function overwrite`.

Answer (score 2):

Because your reference is a type `A`, only the `A` methods will be considered when deciding what to call. Since `print(A)` was virtual, it will actually call the method from `B` that matches the signature from `A`.

If this is confusing, consider if you had added a method `foo` to `B`. What would happen if you tried to call `a.foo()`? It would fail, because objects of type `A` don't have a `foo` method.